# How to recover the deleted repository and the deleted branch

Tags: git, openstack, gerrit

Please help me! I made a stupid mistake. When I followed this link: http://docs.openstack.org/infra/manual/developers.html

I created a new branch and made changes for Gerrit view. In a stupid moment, I deleted the branch with command: `git branch -D mybranch`

And then I also deleted projectname which was cloned to my computer: `sudo rm -rf projectname`

(projectname is gotten with the command: `git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack/<projectname>`)

Now I want to recover the projectname in order to continue to make changes. I see that OpenStack gerrit still displays the change for deleleted branch. Please help me recover it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a core developer in OpenStack, here is a very simple solution for recovering such **uploaded but not approved yet** patch, let's take an example:

I have a patch **already** push to gerrit: https://review.openstack.org/#/c/309710/

my local working directly is: /opt/stack/aodh, and the branch name is: fix-some-bug

Then for some reason I permanently removed the working directory, but it is easy to recover **if you have the code on gerrit**

`cd /opt/stack && git clone https://github.com/openstack/aodh && cd aodh`

now, open a web browser and go to gerrit web page, find your patch: https://review.openstack.org/#/c/309710/ , there is a small drop down button on right top, named "Download", click it and choose the first one, the checkout one, then click the little black button on the right side, which will copy the url to you paste board

now, switch to you shell windows, just paste it:

`git fetch https://git.openstack.org/openstack/aodh refs/changes/10/309710/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

you patch will be downloaded and you should follow the shell prompt, do a checkout: `git checkout -b fix-some-bug` to enable you switch to another branch later without losing your code

now, you can continue your work, cheers!

PS: replace all the example with your real one

Comment: Actually, you saved my life! :D
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @ZhiQiang, I hope you still follow this thread. I have one more question and need your help. In my spec, I got a failure with "gate-something-docs" which is similar to "gate-aodh-docs" in your case. When I read console.html, I see an error like: ERROR:   venv: commands failed. Please let me know how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: you should run tox -edocs under your working directory to check if there is anything related to doc issue. gate almost does same thing with the local check, because it runs tox -edocs as well

Answer (score 2):

> `git branch -D mybranch`

This command delete the local branch (which can still be recovered. we will get to it later - next paragraph)

> `sudo rm -rf projectname`

**`OOPS`**... you have just deleted the repository and the local data with the deleted branch (So you cant recover it locally any more)

---

### ***`What else can you do to recover it?`***

> I see that OpenStack gerrit still displays the change for deleted branch

Looks like you have the branch on your remote repository.
Clone the project, checkout the branch and continue your work.

```
# Clone the project
git clone <url>

# checkout the desired branch
git checkout <branch>
```

And you have the latest code **which was committed (and pushed)** your local changes are gone...

Comment: Yeah, right. You showed my problem. I already cloned the project but it did not work anymore:

git clone -b mybranch https://git.openstack.org/openstack/projectname.git

Because my branch is just for review. So, I cannot clone

Comment: I miss the last comment? you cloned and the branch is not there?

Comment: yes,right. The original notice is:

fatal: Remote branch mybranch not found in upstream origin

Comment: If you don't have the branch you have to grab the content from the OpenStack file system and create branch from it.

Comment: I am not sure you are clear my problem. As I say, I already cloned a project in OpenStack file system and also created new branch. But I did some mistakes.

Please confirm that when I clone with the command "git clone -b mybranch git.openstack.org/openstack/projectname.git". Is correct?

Comment: you can simply clone without the -b. this should bring all the branches references and not only the desired branch,

Comment: Still error:
fatal: repository 'mybranch' does not exist

Maybe I have al little bit experience with git. But I think the problem is that my branch has not approved yet. Therefore, it will not exist, right?

Thanks

Comment: One more question is that if I clone OpenStack project: "git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack/<projectname>.git" and type "git checkout <branch>". New branch has same name with the deleted one. So, It still works? :D

Thanks

Comment: yep, you will get the latest commits that you have pushed. You have lost all the uncommitted data

Comment: Thanks. Really, I don't want to have any mistake :D
So, please note that I said "It still works", it means I can make changes in OpenStack gerrit with this branch, right?